# Evaluate $\hat f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-itx}dt$ for $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}1_{[-2,2]}(x-2n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

> $\hat f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-itx}dt$, for $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$
>
> Let $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}1_{[-2,2]}(t-2n)$, where $1_{[.,.]}$ is the indicator function
>
> I want to determine $\hat f(x).$

I think we need to interchange the series and the integral which should be no problem because

$\frac{1}{2^n}1_{[-2,2]}(x-2n) \ge 0$ so we can use Fubini.

Now, using $1_{[-2,2]}(x-2n)=1_{[2n-2,2n+2]}(x)$:

$\hat f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1_{[2n-2,2n+2]}(t)e^{-itx}dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{e^{-i(2n+2)}-e^{-i(2n-2)}}{-ix}$

Is that correct so far?
I thought about using $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ to simplify this term but I don't know if that will help

Answer (score 1):

If you are also required to be rigorous you have to justify the interchange of the integral and the infinite sum. You can do this by observing that  your sereis converges in $L^{1}$ norm and $s_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$ norm  implies $\hat {s_n} \to \hat {f}$ pointwise. [Take $s_n$ to be the n-th partial sum of the series].

Comment: If we interpret the sum as an integral wrt the counting measure, then we can apply Fubini if, for instance, the integrand is $\ge 0$. In my example the summands are $\ge$ 0 so we can interchange the integral with the infnite sum. The 'worst' thing that can happen (which does not happen here), is that the series diverges but then the interchanged term also equals $\infty$. 

So I think you want to use dominated convergence and I use Fubini, and both should work here if I am correct

Comment: Because of the factor $e^{-itx]$ you don't really have non-negative terms. But you can apply Fubini's Theorem by verifying integrability on the product space.  @user700332

Comment: Okay. The series converges in $L^1$ norm because $|f(x)|\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1/2^n< \infty$? 
How would I evaluate $\|f\|_1$?

Comment: By Tonelli's Theorem and translation invariance of Lebesgue measure $\int f(x)dx \sum \frac 4 {2^{n}=8$.

Comment: Can you explain how the rigorous reasoning for interchanging the limit and integral looks like? I dont fully understand yet

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, but at end there is no need to that formulas for simplification of sum. Just observe that all terms display in positive and negative, so annihilate each other, but these two:
$$\hat{f}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\frac{e^{-2i}}{ix}+\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{ix})$$